# Why is 'a' used in "There's a good many reasons why people should follow it"?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, prepositions, articles, sentence-patterns

> There's a good many reasons why people should follow it.

Why is there an 'a' before 'good many reasons'?

Comment: It is an idiomatic expression: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/good-many

Comment: Have you looked in any dictionaries? Many include the phrase "a good many". (If you are looking for its etymology, then please clarify.) Also, that phrase is usually construed as plural.

Comment: I am not convinced that the singular usage is common. Can you quote sources?

Comment: It's bad grammar.  Not the "a", but "is".  It should be "There are a good many reasons why people should follow it."

Comment: @Anton ***A*** few possible ***ʀᴇᴀꜱᴏɴꜱ ᴅᴏ*** exist for using the nominally singular indefinite article *a/an* with **quantiﬁed plural nouns** without this having any effect at all on their inherently plural grammatical number for verb agreement purposes, and some of these are explored in answers to the selected  duplicates that ***ᴀ*** lot of ***ᴘᴇᴏᴘʟᴇ ᴀʀᴇ*** investigating even now as we speak. :)